# Updating Property in callback with Controller As

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, angularjs-controlleras

I'm working on an AngularJS project using ES6 and Controller As syntax and running into some new issues.  I have a `ng-repeat` which calls a function to update some data.  I want the item passed to a function within `ng-repeat` to be updated when a promise returns.  The issue is I can't seem to reference it again after the promise comes back.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.thing.items">
  <div ng-click="updateItem(item)">Update Item</div>
</div>
```

Then the update function here:

```
updateItem(item) {
    let i = new this.Item(item);
    i.update().then(function(response) {
        item = response.data; // Item does not get updated in controller
    });
}
```

I've tried setting item to a variable within the function and various other things I could try to re-reference, but have been unsuccessful.

The only success I've had is passing the index and then referencing the original object by setting a `let t = this;` before the promise and then `t.thing.items[index] = response.data`.  This works, but feels a bit ugly compared to usually being able to reference objects more directly.  What am I missing here?

Comment: please try, `angular.merge(item, response.data);`

Comment: or angular.extend(item, response.data) depending on your needs

Answer (score 0):

As you've pointed out, by calling `item =` you are actually just reassigning the reference to the parameter being passed into `updateItem` - you're not actually updating the original `item` object.

To get around this, you could update the properties of `item` with all of the data from `response.data` using `Object.assign`:

```
updateItem(item) {
    let i = new this.Item(item);
    i.update().then(function(response) {
        Object.assign(item, response.data); // Copy the enumerable properties from response.data into item
    });
}
```

Note however that won't *delete* any properties that were previously in `item` but are no longer in `response.data`;

Comment: Can I reassign the reference and have it updated throughout?  I just tried Object.assign and it does then update the view with other changes whereas reassignment does not.  I feel like previously I have reassigned the object passed in and it has worked how I expected it here to, although I haven't slept in quite a while so I may I'm not thinking clearly.

Comment: Been a while since I used Angular myself, so also might not be thinking clearly, but I'm pretty sure this is the only way to do this unless you're binding the variable to a service, or directly onto the controller, e.g. `$scope.item = ` may have worked, but you would need to pass the scope into `updateItem` too